# NLog getting current user causes error to appear

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core, nlog

This is my target

```
<target xsi:type="Database" name="database"
   connectionString="${var:connectionString}"
   commandText="INSERT INTO [AppOne].[EventLogs](Id, Message, Level, Logger, Action,Identity)VALUES(NewID(), @Message, @Level, @Logger, @Action,@Identity)">
<parameter name="@Message" layout="${message}" />
<parameter name="@Level" layout="${level}" />
<parameter name="@Logger" layout="${logger}" />
<parameter name="@Action" layout="${aspnet-mvc-action}"/>
<parameter name="@Identity" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}"/>
```

I have also placed this line in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddSingleton<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

However, when I run my application and try to log an item, I get this error in the internal log:

> Error DatabaseTarget(Name=database): Error when writing to database.
>   Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'Identity'.

I am using Asp.net Core 2.1. I tried searching through the documentation and it looks like this supports asp.net only?

Comment: Identity is a keyword, wrap it with square brackets `[Identity]` in your insert statement

Comment: Oh it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used a keyword as a column name, I would avoid doing this if you can to stop issues like this occurring. You can however resolve the error by wrapping the keyword in square brackets, so your SQL should be

`INSERT INTO [AppOne].[EventLogs](Id, [Message], [Level], Logger, [Action],[Identity])VALUES(NewID(), @Message, @Level, @Logger, @Action,@Identity)`